how would i use equivalent circuit to calculate gain of common emitter with inductor load?
I would like to calculate the gain of a common emitter that has an inductor load.Here is the picture of what I am trying to learn. I want to calculate the gain if the inductor is an RFC.


How would an inductor be seen at DC, medium and very high frequencies? And have you drawn an equivalent circuit? That may help.

You can treat the collector of the BJT as a constant current source, assuming it's not saturating or in cut-off. (And also neglecting stuff like the Early effect for now.) With that, you can split the circuit into two pieces: The constant-current "driver" (containing everything but the inductor), and the load, which in this case is just the inductor.
The "driver" side of things - including the biasing resistor, emitter degeneration resistor, and BJT - boils down to a simple transconductance stage with a gain g. It linearly translates the AC input voltage into an AC output current, which is then fed into the load inductor. Note that the gain g is the overall voltage-to-current gain of the BJT stage, including the emitter degeneration resistor. You can calculate it as g = 1 / (RE + 1/gm), where gm is the BJT's inherent transconductance and RE is the emitter resistor.
In short:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
If you take the Early effect into account as well, you'll get an additional (high-value) resistor in parallel to the load inductor. You might actually want to physically add a resistor in parallel there too to limit the gain at high frequencies to something reasonable.
Given a certain signal frequency, you can calculate the impedance of the inductor as Z = j 2pi f L and then apply Ohm's law to get the output voltage from the collector current.
Overall, you should arrive at A = j 2pi f L g, making this circuit a differentiator.
Plugging the expression for g back in, this gives A = j 2pi f L / (RE + 1/gm).

what about the emitter resistor? doesn't this make A = j2pi f L gm/(Re)?

@xcaliber99 I meant the overall voltage-to-current gain of the BJT stage with "gm" here, including the emitter degeneration resistor. I'll update the answer to clarify.

i confused g with gm. now i see it. if the emitter resistor weren't there, it would be gmj2pif*L=A. With the emitter resistor, you end up with collector impedance divided by emitter impedance. Would it be the same way if We had an inductor as an emitter impedance?

@xcaliber99 The formula at the end of the answer is exactly that: Collector impedance divided by emitter impedance. (For an ideal transistor with infinite gm, the formula simplifies to A = j 2pi f L / RE)

oh ok. idk if this would require a new post but my question is very related to this and a similar case. If we switched the emitter resistor with an inductor, would the gain be the collector inductor impedance/emitter inductor impedance?

@xcaliber99 That's correct. And given that both impedances are proportional to frequency, the frequency dependence would cancel out and it'd (theoretically) result in constant gain over frequency. In practice, the current through the transistor would increase almost without bounds and destroy it as the emitter inductor would act as a short.

but why is it used in power amplifier design and LNA design if it would destroy the transistors?

@xcaliber99 I don't think Jonathan put much into the answer. Admitted. But it's also unfair for you to slip in LNAs. Your question centers on an impractical circuit. (I've not seen it used exactly as shown.) Now you radically change the goal post positions to what has to be quite practical -- and involves a lot of theory and practice that your bare-bones question avoids entirely. The complex realities of an LNA design require a fair bit of writing that wasn't implied in your question. Should have included details of where you were going, I think.

@xcaliber99 LNAs use a different biasing scheme for the transistors, which ensures that the collector current is limited to a reasonable value. Your circuit in particular would destroy the transistor if you switched the emitter resistor for an inductor without also modifying the base bias.
